# mysql 8.0.24 root password reset not working

Tags: mysql

I know this topic is discussed in many threads but I still cannot find the solution for my case.
I am using mysql 8.0.24 in centOS 8.0 and trying to reset my root password. Here is my user table.

```
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
```

I first started with [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) with below command.

```
`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '111';`
```

But I got error, `ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'`
And I tried with

`update mysql.user set authentication_string='111' where user='root';`

I got `Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)`.
Then I did

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I checked the table with

```
mysql> SELECT user,authentication_string FROM mysql.user;

+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user             | authentication_string                                                  |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| mysql.infoschema | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED |
| mysql.session    | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED |
| mysql.sys        | $A$005$THISISACOMBINATIONOFINVALIDSALTANDPASSWORDTHATMUSTNEVERBRBEUSED |
| root             | 111                                                                    |
```

Then I kill the safemode and start in normal model with

```
systemctl start mysqld
mysql -u root -h localhost -p
```

When I type the password 111, it says

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I really don't know why this happened. First of all, the official docs syntax doesn't work for my version. I used the update command. Nothing works.

Comment: According to the very same docs you linked the `alter user` command is not to be executed in the MySQL shell but within a `mysql-init` file.

Answer (score 1):

Change the root user’s authentication method to one that uses a password

```
sudo mysql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
exit
```

and then try to login by password.

You may change the root user’s authentication method back to the default

```
mysql -u root -p
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket;
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved by using another method. Thank the people for answering my question. In case someone tracks to here. I would like to provide them with some ideas.
What I did is I drop the root user in the safe mode according to this thread's the highest score answer [cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04/784347#784347).
Below command works for me. Someone might not know what is Identified with caching_sha2_password. You can select 'plug in' the user table. It tells you.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then as the other threads, I can log in with my new password as root user. Hopes this help you.